# How to make compileGroovy run before compileKotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, groovy

following is my build.gradle

```
compileGroovy.dependsOn -= compileJava

compileKotlin {
    dependsOn compileGroovy
}
```

it raise err

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:compileGroovy
\--- :compileJava
     \--- :compileKotlin
          \--- :compileGroovy (*)
```

but debug compileGroovy.dependsOn in idea, the dependsOn is empty

[image]

I's confused, how to fix above Circular dependency and make first run compileGroovy and then run compileKotlin